# Thread safety of HashSet in parallelStream

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-stream, hashset

Is it safe to use effectively final `HashSet` in a predicate function of a parallel stream?

If not, what would be a good data structure to use? I don't see a `ConcurrentSet`... I suppose I could use a `ConcurrentHashMap.entrySet()`.

From what I was able to gather, even when HashSet is not modified, latest state might not be available in all threads. But maybe there is a simple trick to make it available?

```
List<Integer> items = Stream
    .of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

Set<Integer> exclude = Stream
    .of(5, 10, 15)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());

List<Integer> filtered = items
    .parallelStream()
    .filter(num -> !exclude.contains(num))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Yes, that should be fine.

Comment: As for thread-safe set, you can use `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't modify the set in parallel threads, it should be perfectly safe to use the way your example describes.